# Visible Image buildup from top to bottom: is there a way to show in one stroke?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, firefox

I am using javascript to periodically replace a .png picture, which ist viewed fullscreen as the only content of a site. No matter how I try, in Firefox, after being loaded (as seen via firebug), the new image is always drawn from top to bottom. This takes some seconds. Is there any way to prevent this and show the picture all at once?

This is my current javascript code:

```
function preloadScreenshotPeriodically(){
    var new_screenshot = new Image();
    new_screenshot.src = "screenshot.png?defeat_firefox_caching=" + counter;
    new_screenshot.id = "screenshot";   
    counter = counter + 1;
    new_screenshot.onload = function(){
        loadScreenshot(new_screenshot);
        setTimeout("preloadScreenshotPeriodically();", 5000);
    };
}

function loadScreenshot(new_screenshot){
    document.getElementById("screenshot").parentNode.replaceChild(new_screenshot, document.screenshot);
}
```

I also tried to use two images, one of them hidden. Then loading the picture in the hidden one and swapping them. Same results :/

In an other version, I fetched the image with Ajax and after loading is complete, changed the url of the img-tag. My hope was, that the browser would recognize the picture had already been loaded and fetch it from the browsercache rather than loading it. But this didn't happen and I ended up with two requests to the server for one picture and the same slow drawing of it as in my other trys.

**edit:**
Now I tried it like suggested in answer 1. While it works just fine if I switch the picture when I load the next one (I don't want this), trying to switch it as soon as it is loaded (what I want) results in a blank window (very short) and visible loading of the picture as described above.

this works:

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    #loaderWin { display:block; height:1px; width:1px; overflow:hidden; }
</style>
<div id="imagewin"></div>
<div id="loaderWin"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var screenshotCount=0;
    function showFirstImage() {
        loadNextImage();
    }

    function showNewImage() {
        loadNextImage();
    }

    function nextImageLoaded() {
    //  swapImage();
    }

    function loadNextImage() {
        swapImage();
        screenshotCount = screenshotCount +1;
        var nextImage = "<img id='loaderWinImg'     src='screenshot.png?x="+screenshotCount+"' onload='nextImageLoaded()' />";
        document.getElementById('loaderWin').innerHTML = nextImage;
    }

    function swapImage() {
        document.getElementById("loaderWinImg").onload = '';
        var newimage=document.getElementById('loaderWin').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('imagewin').innerHTML = newimage;
    }
    var showImages = setInterval("showNewImage()",15000);
    showFirstImage();
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this doesn't work:

```
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    #loaderWin { display:block; height:1px; width:1px; overflow:hidden; }
</style>
<div id="imagewin"></div>
<div id="loaderWin"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var screenshotCount=0;
    function showFirstImage() {
        loadNextImage();
    }

    function showNewImage() {
        loadNextImage();
    }

    function nextImageLoaded() {
        swapImage();
    }

    function loadNextImage() {
        screenshotCount = screenshotCount +1;
        var nextImage = "<img id='loaderWinImg'     src='screenshot.png?x="+screenshotCount+"' onload='nextImageLoaded()' />";
        document.getElementById('loaderWin').innerHTML = nextImage;
    }

function swapImage() {
    //  loadNextImage();
        document.getElementById("loaderWinImg").onload = '';
        var newimage=document.getElementById('loaderWin').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('imagewin').innerHTML = newimage;
    }
    var showImages = setInterval("showNewImage()",15000);
    showFirstImage();
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem can be seen here (in firefox problem like described above, in chrome there are no pauses between pictureloads and there is a blank window in between picture changes): http://sabine-schneider.silbe.org:1666/test.html

And here, what Rob suggested in answer 1 without any changes (displays the picture fine in firefox, but not in chrome - there I get a blank window in between picture changes): http://sabine-schneider.silbe.org:1666/test0.html

Comment: Can you link to the page showing the problem?  This shouldn't be happening, unless you image is _extremely_ large...

Comment: Ok, I edited the question. There is a link now, which shows the problem.

Comment: Weird.  I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=757306

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the image is "progressive" ( interlaced) and the preload needs more time for it to complete download.

You can set a width and height to the image also for a more stable presentation

( poss )

using

```
  ?defeat_firefox_caching=" + counter;
```

means you never cache the image ( which has confused me about your question ) - remove that line( unless you need it for something you haven't mentioned)

---

update: Can you try ...

---

```
 <style type="text/css">
   #loaderWin { display:block; height:1px; width:1px; overflow:hidden; }
 </style>

 <div id="imagewin"></div>

 <div id="loaderWin"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var screenshotCount=0;
    function showNewImage() {
    screenshotCount = screenshotCount +1;
     var newimage=document.getElementById('loaderWin').innerHTML;
     document.getElementById('imagewin').innerHTML = newimage;

     var nextImage = "<img src='screenshot.png?defeat_firefox_caching="+screenshotCoun+"'/>";
     document.getElementById('loaderWin').innerHTML = nextImage;

    }

    var showImages = setInterval("showNewImage()",5000);
  </script>
```

Comment: identify -verbose tells me, the image is not interlaced. Setting width and height doesn't help. The point with that line you mentioned is, that I basically fetch the same file over and over again, only its content changes. So I want the browser to really get it every time from the server.

Comment: ok, next check (poss ) if you call the image directly , does it take less than 5 seconds to load ( your 5000 wait time ) ?

Comment: what do you mean by "call directly"? The GET-Request to fetch the picture usually takes slightly less than 5 seconds, most time is used by the server generating the file.

Comment: call directly ( perhaps my term sorry) in the browser address bar with      http://yoursever/screenshot.png?nocache=87897

Comment: if not set to "progressive" download, what do you mean by "loads top to bottom" then ?

Comment: displays top to bottom. I see now, I pointed out Firefox, because there are browsers which don't do that, but I did not write that. In Google Chrome for example the picture is right there without any problems. Even if I request it directly through the browser - the picture is not that big an at the moment everything is localhost.

Comment: ok, not sure if helps but I have updated the answer to try another approach = with hide/show, which you said you have tried,  images do not load into elements with display:none set - this loads the image into a small div ( 1x1) and then we grab the html out of it - might help